# Get value from Table on Azure Mobile Service

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-mobile-services

I apologize for my English language. 
I make a little script on schedule of Azure Mobile Service.

It is supposed to check particular values from my table. But I'm just a newbie on node.js so I really can't figure out with this stuff.

I've found good example how to get one line from table depending on query. But could you tell me, how could I get particular "cell"?

```
var azure = require('azure');
exports.getActive = function (success, failure) {
    // azure.tables doesn't work either
    // tables no go
    tables.getTable('mytable').where({ active: true }).read(
        {
            success: function (results) {
                var result;
                if (results.length > 0) {
                    result = results[0];
                    success(result);

                } else {
                    failure("error");
                }

            },
            error: function (err) {
                failure(err);
            }
        }
        );
}
```

And I would be very greatfull if you advised me good articles about this stuff.

Comment: Is this code running in an API or a table? Are you calling it from somewhere else, or expecting that the service will call it for you?

Answer (score 0):

In Node.js backend Mobile Service, we can leverage several global modules defined in node.js runtime by Mobile Service.

Generally, in mobile service scheduled jobs, you can access tables from your script is by using the [tables object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windowsazure/jj614364.aspx).

The `tables.getTable` function returns a table object instance that's a proxy for accessing the requested table. You can then call functions on the proxy to access and change data.

You can refer to [the section `How to: Access tables from scripts` of the doc `Work with a JavaScript backend mobile service`](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-how-to-use-server-scripts/#working-with-tables) for more information.

Here is my test code snippet.

```
function testsql() {
    // work with tables object
    var todoItemsTable = tables.getTable('TodoItem');
    todoItemsTable.read({
        success:function(data){
        console.log(data)
    }
});
```